# GDI+ Double Buffering [C++]

Tags: c++, double, gdi+, gdi, buffering

I have a problem with my GDI Code.
I use C++.
Here is the code:

```
int main()
{


    DWORD pwdGDIStartup;
    GdiplusStartupInput GDIstartupInp;
    GdiplusStartup(&pwdGDIStartup, &GDIstartupInp, NULL);
    Pen pnPen_Blue(Gdiplus::Color(255, 0, 0, 255), 2.0F);
    PAINTSTRUCT  ps;

    LPCSTR LGameWindow = "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive";

    HWND hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL, LGameWindow);
    Graphics graphics(GetDC(hGameWindow));

    WCHAR string[] = L"Das";

    HDC          hdc;
    HDC          hdcBuffer;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hGameWindow, &ps);

    int i = 10000;

    Font myFont(L"Arial", 10);
    RectF layoutRect(100.00f, 100.00f, 100.00f, 150.00f);
    StringFormat format;
    format.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
    SolidBrush blackBrush(Color(255, 255, 100, 0));
    ;
    for (;;) {
        graphics.DrawString(
            string,
            11,
            &myFont,
            layoutRect,
            &format,
            &blackBrush);
        i++;
        graphics.DrawLine(&pnPen_Blue, 300, 700, 500, 600);
        graphics.DrawLine(&pnPen_Blue, 400, 700, 400, 600);

    }


}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: I have updated your question to include the code, but right now it's not clear what you're asking. You need to say what you're trying to do, what you've tried, what you expect to happen and what's actually happening.

Comment: Drawing on the windows you don't own using straightforward GDI is not going to work.

Comment: Hey, you need to ask a specific question for us to be able to help you.

Comment: K 
Yeah it´s Flickering that´s my problem

Comment: The code is just splattering pixels on a window owned by another process, completely out of sync with that program's render loop.  It not just that it will flicker, it *must* flicker.  Consider overlapping the program's game window with a layered window you create yourself to get ahead.

Comment: Can you recode my code?